# Restore trained tensorflow model, edit the value associated with a node, and save it

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have trained a model with tensorflow and used batch normalization during training. Batch normalization requires the user to pass a boolean, called `is_training`, to set whether the model is in training or testing phase.

When the model was trained, `is_training` was set as a constant as shown below

```
is_training = tf.constant(True, dtype=tf.bool, name='is_training')
```

I have saved the trained model, the files include checkpoint, .meta file, .index file, and a .data. I'd like to restore the model and run inference using it.
The model can't be retrained. So, I'd like to restore the existing model, set the value of `is_training` to `False` and then save the model back. 
How can I edit the boolean value associated with that node, and save the model again?

Comment: it would have been easier if you used `is_training=tf.Variable..` rather than constant

Comment: Is there a reason why `is_training` needs to be a tensorflow constant? Can't it be a python bool? Note that changing `is_training` to a python bool should not give errors in restoring the model.

Comment: @GeertH It can be, the question is how do I set `is_training` to `False` after I load the model, then save it back. So that when it is restored again, the node has value `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `input_map` argument of [`tf.train.import_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) to remap the graph tensor to a updated value.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    # define the new is_training tensor
    is_training = tf.constant(False, dtype=tf.bool, name='is_training')

    # now import the graph using the .meta file of the checkpoint
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
    '/path/to/model.meta', input_map={'is_training:0':is_training})

    # restore all weights using the model checkpoint 
    saver.restore(sess, '/path/to/model')

    # save updated graph and variables values
    saver.save(sess, '/path/to/new-model-name')
```

Comment: The above code throws an error `ValueError: tf.import_graph_def() requires a non-empty name if input_map is used`

Comment: I have tested this code using `tensorflow==1.2.0`, hope it helps; ALSO its not `tf.import_graph_def`. see my code.

Comment: I tried your code the way it is, the error is thrown by this line, `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'D:\code\iprings\k-fold-model\VanillaCNN_24.0000.meta', input_map={'is_training':is_training})`

Comment: i would suggest you to use tf==1.2.0